# Beginner PyTorch : RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [16 x 2304000], m2: [600 x 120]

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I'm a beginner with PyTorch and building NNs in general and I'm kinda stuck.

I have this CNN architecture:

```
class ConvNet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, num_classes=10):
        super(ConvNet, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=3, 
            out_channels=16, 
            kernel_size=3)

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=16, 
            out_channels=24, 
            kernel_size=4)

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=24, 
            out_channels=32, 
            kernel_size=4)

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout2d(p=0.3)

        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(600, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 10)

        self.final = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):

        # conv 3 layers

        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), 2)  # output of conv layers
        x = self.dropout(x)

        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), 2)  # output of conv layers
        x = self.dropout(x)

        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv3(x)), 2)  # output of conv layers
        x = self.dropout(x)

        # linear layer

        x = F.interpolate(x, size=(600, 120))
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)

        x = self.fc1(x) 

        return x
```

But when I try to train with my images, it doesn't work and I have this error:

```
RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [16 x 2304000], m2: [600 x 120]
```

I would like to add a second linear layer (`self.fc2`) as well as a final SoftMax layer (`self.final`) but since I'm stuck at the first linear layer I cannot make any progress.

Comment: in my DataLoader it's written batch_size=16

Comment: I'm not sure, could you tell me how to find this?

Comment: Ok. I have added a line `print(x.shape)` before my first layer and after each layer. So in total I have 5 printing line, and here are the outputs: `torch.Size([16, 3, 256, 256])`, `torch.Size([16, 16, 127, 127])`, `torch.Size([16, 24, 62, 62])`, `torch.Size([16, 32, 29, 29])`, `torch.Size([16, 2304000])`

Comment: Okay, I just changed it. Here are the new outputs: `torch.Size([16, 3, 256, 256])`, `torch.Size([16, 16, 127, 127])`, `torch.Size([16, 24, 62, 62])`, `torch.Size([16, 32, 30, 30])`, `torch.Size([16, 2304000])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input dimension of `self.fc1` needs to match the feature (second) dimension of your flattened tensor. So instead of doing `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(600, 120)`, you can replace this with `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2304000, 120)`.

Keep in mind that because you are using fully-connected layers, the model cannot be input size invariant (unlike Fully-Convolutional Networks). If you change the size of the channel or spatial dimensions before `x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)` (like you did moving from the last question to this one), the input dimension of `self.fc1` will have to change accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, it's now working. I have two questions: 1. It seems extremely slow, after 3mn on Google Colab i'm only at batch 52 from Epoch 1. I want to do 10 epochs but I feel like it's going to take 3 hours? is that normal? 2. How does the model get "saved"? I understand there's a function to save it with `torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)` but how do I use it for, say, my test dataset after having used it for the train dataset? thanks.

Comment: You can try increasing the batch size (if memory allows) for faster computation. Just to double check, are you running this with cuda?

Comment: You normally save something like `state = {"model": model.state_dict(), "optimizer": optimizer.state_dict()}` etc with whatever variables you'd like to retain. This can then be loaded by `checkpoint = torch.load(pt file)` and `model.load_state_dict(checkpoint["model"])` etc.

Comment: Thanks so much! I wasn't running it with Cuda and now I've looked into it and implemented it, it's like 10x faster!

Comment: Do you have any idea why my loss doesn't decrease? It starts at 0.002 and stays the same for any number of iteration.